# Abs[.] breaks my infinite sum

Tags: summation

The following evaluates correctly to pi^2/4:

```
Sum[n^2  (Sin[n π]/(-1 + n^2))^2, {n, 1, ∞}]
```

The following gives a 1/0 error:

```
Sum[n^2  (Abs[Sin[n π]/(-1 + n^2)])^2, {n, 1, ∞}]
```

Why is that?

Comment: `Assuming[n > 0, Sum[n^2 (Abs[Sin[n \[Pi]]/(-1 + n^2)])^2, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]]` evaluates to `Pi^2/4`, too.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you say the first is correct? Its first term is indeterminate. For a guess, `Sum` used an analytic method that treated `n` as continuous internally, and removed the removable singularity at `n==1`, thus doing what you **intended** but not what you actually **asked**. When you used the non-analytic function `Abs`, it didn't do that.

More commentary in response to @Nasser:

The numerator of the function is always zero, so only the first term, whose denominator is zero, matters. Then:

```
Limit[n^2 (Sin[n \[Pi]]/(-1 + n^2))^2, n -> 1]
(* \[Pi]^2/4 *)
```

So, in a peculiar sense, the first sum is correct. That sense seems to be what @user120404 intended. I don't consider it correct, but perhaps this odd corner case is difficult for *Mathematica* to detect.

Comment: Do you think Mathematica answer is then correct giving `Pi^2/4`? Is this a known series?  Strange it sums it even with 1/0 being there.

Comment: When n=1, you get `0/0`. In the limit, though, as n approaches 1, you get `Pi2/4`.

Comment: @rhomboidRhipper sorry, meant to say Mathematica gives error `Indeterminate` for `n=1`. This happens in both cases. Since `0/0` is not defined. Does this mean Mathematica can do sum even if some terms in the series are `Indeterminate`?